# Passing parameter to GWT module

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

My GWT module UI is only single button (*like AddThis/ShareThis Sharing Button*), and all other stuff is done in JS Popup panels. **Id** is specified as Global JS variable (*i.e. myConfig.id=22*) and getting that Id in GWT module using JSNI method (*$wnd.myConfig.id*).

**NOTE:** There is also another way pass parameter, which is by setting

```
<div id='gwtRootPanel' alt='6323'> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.test.gwt.Common/com.test.gwt.Common.nocache.js"></script>
```

& in GWT code

```
RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("gwtRootPanel");
System.out.println("Passed Value " + DOM.getElementAttribute(rootPanel.getElement(), "alt"));
```

---

Both way works fine for only 1 button in page, Now I dont see any of this option feasible for adding multiple buttons (*like same Share button for each blog in Blog Post list*) in one HTML page..

If Using 1st way,
How to get different values for same GWT compiled file?

If using 2nd way,
Cannot use same  < div id='gwtRootPanel' >...

**Any Hint or solution?**

Cheers,
Nachiket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to use multiple entry points on the same page. Instead use a single entry point and place markers on your page where you want it to interact.

So if you want to stick a GWT button widget within certain divs, you might implement your html like this:

```
<div id="marker1"></div>
<!-- more stuff -->
<div id="marker2"></div>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Then the entry point to your single GWT app would insert its own buttons from a loop like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  int i = 1;
  do {
    String id = "marker" + i;
    RootPanel rp = RootPanel.get(id);
    if (rp == null) {
      break;
    }
    rp.add(new MyWidget(getContextData(id)));
    i++;
  } while (true);
}

native String getContextData(String id) /*-{
  return $wnd.myConfig[id];
}-*/;
```

So this example would iterate through the html looking for matching ids and then insert widgets as child elements there. Additionally it uses the id as a context to get some more data which is in the page.

Comment: Did something similar already.. 
Set external JS config variable which provides Array of DIV id.. But your solution is more simple & elegant. Thanks for the answer. :)